# How to store application sessions into Static instance correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, static

We are storing the all the application sessions into Global class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
namespace MyApp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AppSession : IRequiresSessionState
    {
        //Name that will be used as key for Session object
        private const string SESSION_SINGLETON = "MyappSession";

        string _UserName;
        int? _UserID ,_ClientID;
        public int? UserID
        {
            get
            {
                return _UserID;
            }
            set
            {
                _UserID = value;
            }
        }
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return _UserName;
            }
            set
            {
                _UserName = value;
            }
        }
        public int? ClientID
        {    
            get
            {
                return _ClientID;
            }
            set
            {
                _ClientID = value;
            }
        }
        public MarketingSession Marketing { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

We have created another class property to maintain that Page sessions into different `MarketingSession` class as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MyApp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MarketingSession : IRequiresSessionState
    {
        private int? _ChannelId;    
        public int? ChallelId { get 
        { 
            return _ChannelId; }
            set { _ChannelId = value; }
        }    
    }
}
```

I am not 100% sure that is it correct way to maintain Session in class or not.
and Is it ok to create Non-Static another Class object in this Session.

I am getting error as below when I added `MarketingSession` Class property.

> Error 10  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property `MyApp.AppSession.Marketing.get`

Update me if I am doing right way to manage my application sessions or not?
If way is correct then How to fix the error ?

Comment: Show the code in which you initialize your MarketingSession object.

Comment: Not initialize in the AppSession class. Am going to correct way? should i use static member in MarketingSession property in AppSession class?

Comment: MyApp.AppSession.Marketing.get - you're using this method as if it was static. You need to initialize your AppSession object before accessing its properties, or declare them static in the first place.

Comment: @TommyNaidich how? Either I have to create initialize in constructor or make Marketing property static? what is the perfect way to manage it.. we will use separate class to use session property in AppSession class to manage it.

Comment: If I make this wit static "public static MarketingSession Marketing { get; set; } " then it working. but it is correct way or create initialize with new  object in constructor.?

Comment: Consider using the [Singleton Pattern] in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [Singleton Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) seems like the best solution in your case.
You want to initialize your Marketing object only once, and share its value among all of your AppSession class instances.

This is exactly what this pattern is used for. 
Make sure to read some of the following examples on how to use it and have it suit your goals the best way.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

https://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton

Comment: Ok Thank you.. I will do as initialization as per pattern. we already used that pattern..

Comment: Glad I helped. Please make sure to mark your question answered if it is indeed what you were looking for.

Comment: Should I create static object of other Marketing class or Normal object in AppSession class? 
See below.. 
static readonly MarketingSession _ms = new MarketingSession();
 public MarketingSession Marketing
        {
            get
            {
                return _ms;
            }
        }

or do i have ? public MarketingSession Marketing {...}
?

Comment: @AbhishekB. if your MarketingSession is global and relevant to the entire AppSession - put it there and make it static, exactly the way you mentioned in your comment above. Make sure you disable the setter for its property, as it is not to be changed at any time.

Comment: Are you from israel? sky pe "live:tommynaidich" ? correct